# Python MySQL: How to read from database in a module and compare it to input() in main program?

Tags: python, mysql

For example, in my "users" table in my database, there is a column "num" with a value of 10.

main program:

```
import mysql

x = input()    
read = mysql.readinput()

if x == read:
  print("Hello, #10!")
else:
  print("bye")
```

Here is the sample code in the mysql.py module:

```
import MySQLdb

def readinput():
  db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","123","database" )
  cur = db.cursor()
  cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users""") #this may be incorrect
  #(reading of the value of column "num" (which is 10 in my example)) I don't know what to put here, hence my question
```

What do I put (code) in mysql.py so that my main program can read and compare the `input()` and value from the database (assigned to read) to use for `if... else`?

Update: `print read` shows:

```
(('1'',), ('2',), ('4',), ('6',), ('8',), ('10',))
```

These basically are the values inside column "first_name" in the table "users"

What I wanted to happen is, when prompted to `input()`, if 10 is inputted, it prints "Hello, #10!" if not, then "bye".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `fetchall()` function to get query results. Like this:

```
import MySQLdb

def readinput():
  db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","123","database" )
  cur = db.cursor()
  cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users""")
  # use fetchall to get all the return results which is a list object
  return cur.fetchall()
```

Then in the `main` program you have to compare every item in this list to show the final result. Like this:

```
import mysql

x = input()    
read = mysql.readinput()
print read
for item in read:
    if str(x) == item[0]:
      print("Hello, #10!")
      break
    else:
      print("bye")
```

Comment: Will that also fetch other values from other columns? What if there are other columns that also have the value 10.. because I think column "num" is not specified

Comment: @shindonism Then you only need to change the sql command to "select num from users". No need to change python code.

Comment: @shindonism I've added 'print read' in the code. Tell me what gets printed out.

Comment: I've edited it to `SELECT first_name FROM users` and what `print read` shows are the values inside column first_name..

The output of the program is (without `print read`):
     
    >>10
    >>bye
    >>bye
    >>bye
    >>bye
    >>bye
    >>bye
    
I think it printed the number of values inside the column first_name (or the number of rows) = 6.

Comment: @shindonism So does this answer your question?

Comment: No, it needs to print `Hello, #10!` if 10 is inputted.. and only one `bye` if not..

Comment: @shindonism I think that's because the type is not right. Check my update. And if you only want to compare first element in the read, use break to jump out of the loop.

Comment: I've tried using `SELECT * FROM users` with the `print read` and it shows all the values in the table (more than 20), but still with 6 `bye`. I also updated the code with your update (with the `str(x)` and `break`s) It resulted with blank. Nothing was printed..

Comment: @shindonism Here must be some simple problems. Update your question with output of print read and your expected output. Then I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes! That `item[0]` solved it.. but there are blanks before "Hello, #10!" (5 blanks) then when I tried to input 2, only one blank. I assume the blanks the positions of the values (5 blanks for input 10 because it's the 6th value and 1 blank for input 2 because it's the second value)

Comment: @shindonism It's supposed to be bye instead of blanks. But I think it's the detail of comparison.